# Print Out Name In Specific Way

Tags: c, arrays, character

I must compose a code that prints out a first a last name as follows:
Smith, A.

I've tried various techniques thus far and have accidentally created an infinite "for" loop I believe, although I'm not 100% sure how I did that.  This is specifically for C, I'm relatively new to the language, and despite having read the textbook don't have a great understanding about how characters work inside arrays apparently.  This is likely an easy problem I'm way overthinking.  This is what I've written thus far, excluding unnecessary aspects of the code (ie. defining)

UPDATED CODE

```
int main(void)
{
  char name, letter;
  char fname[MAX], lname[MAX];
  int countf, countl, i, j;

  printf("Enter a first and last name: ");
  countf = 0;
  countl = 0;
  while ((name = getchar()) != ' ') {
      fname[countf++] = name; 
  }

  while ((name = getchar()) != '\n') {
      lname[countl++] = name;
  }

 for(i=0;i < sizeof(lname);i++) {
     putchar(lname[i]);
 }
 printf(", ");
 putchar(fname[0]);
 printf(".");

  return 0;
}
```

I still have some random and unnecessary variables.  The current output is Smith(symbol)t(symbol)~(two symbols), A."  I'm not sure how to get rid of the glitches

Comment: I think you misunderstood some basics. `fname[name]` makes no sense, as it would access the nth character in `fname` and then do nothing with it. Also, `n` in this case is the ASCII code of the char entered. You probably wanted `fname[countf++] = name;`.

Comment: Note that `fname[name];` doesn't do anything, and even if it did, it is wrong to index by the character entered. The reason you get strange results is the arrays are uninitialised, and never have data written to them.

Comment: The `fname[name];` and `lname[name];` statements make no sense.  First, `name` is being used as an index into these arrays, but `name` is a character, not an array index.  And furthermore, assuming the indexing doesn't cause  a segmentation fault, the statements don't do anything.  They're variable access, and their values are just being dropped on the floor.

Comment: Oof ok that's a big error at my part.  I thought that would put the character inside the array for some reason @ThiefMaster and @Weather Vane .  I tried what you said @user3121023 but am not getting "ASCIIl(symbol)t(symbol)~(symbols), `." as an output

Comment: You have to post the actual code that generated the results you claim - this code does not compile (missing `)` in last `putchar()`), so how can we be sure any fix we suggest will fix the real code?

Comment: @Clifford I fixed the code, sorry about that, must have been an error in my copy paste

Comment: I fixed my code and it now works, thank you

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`. And most names are not *single character ones*.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala :  The `int` issue is a fair point, but `getchar()` is called iteratively.  The issue is perhaps the symbol `name` to represent something other than the entire name - confusing rather then invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stop outputting the last name at the end of the valid data, not the end of the array:

```
for( i = 0; i < countl; i++ )
//              ^^^^^^
```

That fixes your code, but you are somewhat over complicating the problem.  You are unnecessarily storing the input, when you only need to store the first letter.  You can then simply discard the rest of the first name, and output the last name directly before finally outputting the stored first letter - thus:

```
int main( void )
{
    printf( "Enter a first and last name: " );

    // Keep first letter to output last.
    char letter = getchar() ;

    // Discard the rest of the first name
    while( getchar() != ' ' )
    {
       // Do nothing until SPACE
    }

    // Output the last name
    int namech = 0 ;
    while( (namech = getchar()) != '\n' )
    {
        putchar( namech ) ;
    }
    printf( ", " );

    // Output the first letter
    putchar( letter ) ;
    printf( "." );

    return 0;
}
```

This has the distinct advantage of being immune from any buffer overrun issues - because there is no buffer.